# How to use previously defined class in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, inventory

I am writing an addition to a java inventory problem that uses an arraylist to write methods to add, search for, etc. items in an inventory.

I am using another class called InventoryItem which has variables for sku, itemName, price, and stock.

I would like to know if I am on the right track in using a perviously defined class in writing a method to add an item.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Warehouse {

      private ArrayList<InventoryItem> inventory = new ArrayList<InventoryItem>();

      public static void addItem(InventoryItem i ) 

          inventory.add(i);

      }

      public static void main(String [] args) {

           addItem();    

      }
}
```

This is the InventoryItem class;

```
public class InventoryItem {

   private int sku;
   private String itemName;
   private double price;
   private int stock;



   public InventoryItem (int sku, String itemName, double price, int stock) {

   this.sku = sku;      
   this.itemName = itemName;
   this.price = price; 
   this.stock = stock;

}

   public int getSku() {

      return sku;

   }


   public String getitemName () {

      return itemName;

   }

   public void setPrice (double price) {

      this.price = price;

   }   

   public double getPrice () {

      return price;

   }

   public void setStock(int stock) {

      this.stock = stock;

   }


   public int getStock() {

      return stock;

   }
    @Override
   public String toString() {

      return String.format("[%d ,%s ,%1.2f ,%d]", sku, itemName, price, stock);

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      InventoryItem itemName = new InventoryItem(1, "asdf", 2.4, 5);
      System.out.println(itemName);

   }

}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. I didn't understand that I had to create the instance variables in the Warehouse class as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major problem with your `addItem()` method is that it is `static`, so it won't be able to access the `warehouse` list, which is an *instance* variable that can only be accessed from an instance.

To fix this (and other) problems, try this:

```
public class Warehouse {
    private List<InventoryItem> inventory = new ArrayList<InventoryItem>();

    public void addItem(InventoryItem i) 
        inventory.add(i);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        // create a Warehouse instance
        Warehouse warehouse = new Warehouse();
        // create an InventoryItem instance 
        InventoryItem i = new InventoryItem(sku, itemName, price, stock);
        // add the InventoryItem to the Warehouse
        warehouse.addItem(i);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right lines. When you call the addItem() method, you will need to pass in an InventoryItem object. So perhaps something more like:

```
double sku = 111;
String itemName = "someItem";
double price = 2.99;
int stock = 1;

InventoryItem inventoryItem = new InventoryItem(sku, itemName, price, stock);
addItem(inventoryItem);
```

You will of course need to make sure you have a constructor in your InventoryItem class which takes in the params that you need.

So, based on your InventoryItem class, and the extra tips from Bohemian below it would look like this:

```
     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.List;

    public class Warehouse {
        private List<InventoryItem> inventory = new ArrayList<InventoryItem>();

        public void addItem(InventoryItem i) {
        inventory.add(i);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        // create a Warehouse instance
        Warehouse warehouse = new Warehouse();
        // create an InventoryItem instance 

        int sku = 111;
        String itemName = "someItem";
        double price = 2.99;
        int stock = 1;

        InventoryItem i = new InventoryItem(sku, itemName, price, stock);
        // add the InventoryItem to the Warehouse
        warehouse.addItem(i);    
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I have a class "InventoryItem" that contains those variables. Is it possible to use that class as a parameter in the arraylist?

Comment: You have already created an array list which contains objects of type InventoryItem (what you have looks correct), you just need to add inventory items to it now. Perhaps if you post up the InventoryItem class I can give you a working example.

Comment: Ok, I posted the InventoryItem class

Comment: I've posted an updated version, it is just a case of making sure you pass the correct params to the constructor. Please also upvote Bohemian, since this solution borrowed his advice too (of making it not static, which may save you a lot of pain in the long run).